# session variable name in MYSQL is being copied verbatim inside CONCAT statement (instead of its value)

Tags: mysql, sql, variables, triggers

I have a trigger which inserts an entry into my notifications table that works great. However I need to add an additional piece of data to the notification string (user name), which I am getting via a SELECT before the INSERT. I put the value in the variable @user_name but when I look at the output string (MESSAGE) in table NOTIFICATIONS, I see my variable name literally in, i.e. "... @user_name ..." instead of the contents of that variable.

I'm totally clueless what is going on because the other arguments to the CONCAT(), for example the NEW.APPID, are clearly being parsed. Why is my @user_name variable not being parsed? I tried to change it to user_name and the same thing happens.

```
delimiter //
CREATE TRIGGER crashes_trigger
AFTER INSERT ON CRASHES
FOR EACH ROW
BEGIN
  SELECT NAME INTO @user_name FROM USER,DEVICE WHERE USER.USERID=DEVICE.USERID AND     DEVICE.DEVICEID=NEW.DEVICEID;
  INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS (TABLENAME, ID, MESSAGE) VALUES ("C1", "1", CONCAT("crash (AppID = ",NEW.APPID,", UserID = “,@user_name,”, DID = ",NEW.DID,", Reason = '", NEW.REASON,"', AV = ", NEW.AV,")"));
END;//
delimiter ;
```

I did a simple test using a variable outside of my trigger and it works as designed. Why are things different in my trigger?

```
mysql> set @test := "hi";
Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.00 sec)

mysql> select concat("(", @test, ")");
+-------------------------+
| concat("(", @test, ")") |
+-------------------------+
| (hi)                    |
+-------------------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

Thanks to a helpful answer I was told that my quotes were mixed up. I fixed that and here is the below portion which was changed:

```
INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS (TABLENAME, ID, MESSAGE) VALUES ("CRASHES", "1", CONCAT("crashed (AppID = ",NEW.APPID,", UserID = ",@user_name,", DID = ",NEW.DID,", Reason = '", NEW.REASON,"', AV = ", NEW.AV,")"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this your intention?

```
INSERT INTO NOTIFICATIONS (TABLENAME, ID, MESSAGE)
    VALUES ("C1", "1",
            CONCAT("crash (AppID = ",NEW.APPID,", UserID = “,", @user_name, ",”, DID = ",NEW.DID,", Reason = '", NEW.REASON,"', AV = ", NEW.AV,")"
                  )
           );
```

MySQL doesn't do variable substitutions within strings.

EDIT:

The problem with your string is actually that you have `“` rather than `"`.  That is, curly quotes instead of "straight" quotes.  I think this is what you really mean:

```
            CONCAT("crash (AppID = ",NEW.APPID,", UserID = ", @user_name, ", DID = ",NEW.DID,", Reason = '", NEW.REASON,"', AV = ", NEW.AV,")"
                  )
```

This can happen when you copy from other applications, such as Word, that insert the curly quotes.

Comment: Yes, that is my insertion. If you look at the last test query in my post you'll see it does do variable substitions within strings. If there is some difference between these two use cases, how can I get done what I need?

Comment: @Locksleyu . . . No.  In the test query, `@test` is an argument to `concat()` (perfectly fine).  In the `insert` query, `@user_name` is between double quotes.

Comment: Gordon, thanks much for pointing that out. I fixed the double quotes (see my update to original post), but now I am getting a NULL result of string. I'll go back to triaging this since it seems there is a different problem, but if you see anything else wrong with my query let me know.

Comment: @Locksleyu . . . `concat()` returns `NULL` if any argument is `NULL`.  Wrap all the variable arguments in a `coalesce()`, something like `coalesce(@user_name, '')`.

Comment: I just found another bug in my test data, when I fixed that, @user_name was non-null, and everything worked. Thanks!!!